# Exporting a graph as graphml in python

Tags: python, graph

I am new to python and I wanted to export a graph (transportation network) which I constructed using a python package called OSMnx. I am unable to export it as a graphml file for further analysis of the network. I have attached the code I used and the error message I am encountering. Please help.

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
G = ox.graph_from_address('Downtown, Saint Louis, MO', network_type='drive')
nx.write_graphml(G, "g.graphml")
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogX2r.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Its better to include the error as text inside your question, as its easier to digest for reader and makes a more complete question.

Answer (score 0):

[OSMnx](http://geoffboeing.com/2016/11/osmnx-python-street-networks/) has a built-in function for saving street networks as GraphML files, to serialize dict attributes of the nodes and edges:

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_address('Downtown, Saint Louis, MO', network_type='drive')
ox.save_graphml(G, filename='g.graphml')
```